# Is it possible to generate Leads from my database

Tags: database

I am using a form on my site to add new leads to a MySQL database. Is it possible to generate my leads in Salesforce from my existing database?

Comment: So you have Leads in a MySQL table and you want them to also live in Salesforce?  Sure, you could create a RESTful end point to POST them

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.

For your existing leads, just export the file (SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...), then import with Setup > Data Management > Data Import Wizard, or you can use the Apex Data Loader.

For new leads, you could use the SOAP API, the REST API, the Web-to-Lead service, Email Services, Bulk API, or custom Apex REST or Web Services.

Comment: @DezOnlyOne ... also, when using Data Loader, decide if you want to run the Lead Assignment Rules, if any, in the org.